# Cannot use vi editor

Tags: linux, vim, vi

When I try to launch vi using `vi` or `vim`, it fails to start.

```
ozzesh:~ # clear
ozzesh:~ # vi 
ozzesh:~ # echo $?
0
ozzesh:~ #
```

The above `vi` / `vim` command can't launch vi.

Comment: What does `which vim` or `type vim` tell you?

Comment: ozzesh:~ # which vim
/usr/bin/vim
ozzesh:~ # type vim
vim is hashed (/usr/bin/vim)
ozzesh:~ #

Comment: Try running `strace vim` or `strace -f vim`.

Comment: ozzesh:~ # strace vim
execve("/usr/bin/vim", ["vim"], [/* 58 vars */]) = -1 ENOEXEC (Exec format error)
dup(2)                                  = 3
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x8002 (flags O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE)
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f545c8a4000
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
write(3, "strace: exec: Exec format error\n", 32strace: exec: Exec format error

Comment: Your `vim` is corrupted. Try reinstalling it: `zypper remove vim ; zypper install vim`

Comment: can I copy one vim-normal of another server?

Comment: Rather not. If the server is different, it might not work.

Comment: no internet connection to the server that I am having problem with
so what to do next?

Comment: How did you install the system? Use the source medium.

Comment: I have copied vim-normal form another server and it worked for me 
thanx all you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Normally vi / vim are located in `/usr/bin`.

Try `/usr/bin/vi` and `/bin/vi`. If these work then your PATH settings need correcting.

Check path, it should contain `/bin` and `/usr/bin` -:

`echo $PATH`

Correct path by reading in your .bash_profile into your current shell (or login again)

```
cd
source .bash_profile
```

Comment: ozzesh:~ # /usr/bin/vi
ozzesh:~ # /bin/vi
ozzesh:~ # echo $PATH
/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/root/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/games:/opt/kde3/bin:/usr/lib/mit/bin:/usr/lib/mit/sbin
ozzesh:~ # 

still not working......

Comment: `ls -l /usr/bin/vim`

Comment: ozzesh:~ # ls -l /usr/bin/vim
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8 May 20  2010 /usr/bin/vim -> /bin/vim
ozzesh:~ #

Comment: `ls -l /bin/vim`

Comment: ozzesh:~ # ls -l /bin/vim
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 May 20  2010 /bin/vim -> /etc/alternatives/vim
ozzesh:~ #

Comment: there is no .bash_profile file for root user do i need the .bash_profile file ?

Comment: Not necessarily. `ls -l /etc/alternatives/vim` - hopefully that's the end of the link lineage.

Comment: ozzesh:~ # ls -l /etc/alternatives/vim 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 May 20  2010 /etc/alternatives/vim -> /bin/vim-normal
ozzesh:~ #

Comment: ok. `ls -l /bin/vim-normal` and `ls -l /bin/vi* /usr/bin/vi*`

Comment: ozzesh:~ # ls -l /bin/vim-normal 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Apr 18 11:02 /bin/vim-normal

Comment: ozzesh:~ # ls -l /bin/vi*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  3 May 20  2010 /bin/vi -> vim
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 May 20  2010 /bin/vim -> /etc/alternatives/vim
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  0 Apr 18 11:02 /bin/vim-normal

Comment: That is your answer. `/bin/vim-normal` is a zero size file. You won't get much editing done with that.

Comment: ozzesh:~ # ls -l /usr/bin/vi*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      8 May 20  2010 /usr/bin/vi -> /bin/vim
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      3 May 20  2010 /usr/bin/view -> vim
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  24080 May  9  2010 /usr/bin/viewres
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      8 May 20  2010 /usr/bin/vim -> /bin/vim
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      3 May 20  2010 /usr/bin/vimdiff -> vim
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   2050 Feb 25  2009 /usr/bin/vimtutor
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  10728 May 12  2010 /usr/bin/vino-passwd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  61496 May 12  2010 /usr/bin/vino-preferences

Comment: I have copied vim-normal form another server and it worked for me thanx all you guys.